# Some notes about managing to access a table in Network SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, network-programming, ssms, multi-user

I have some databases is a one connection. I want put my database in internet to have a network connection so there are some users have access to my database at a same time.

I have some questions about it.

1- Should I manage my tables or database when my users want to edit data at a same time , Or sql will manage it?

2-While I set my database as a Multi-User, Will my database splited like this article [Split Database](http://www.kallal.ca/Articles/split/index.htm)

3- Is there some thing else for have a network connection that I should mention it?

and I know my database should be set as "Online"

I read this article too: [Multiuser Access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171750.aspx)

Comment: What I understood is that you want to allow other users within your local network to have access of your sql server databases? Correct?

Comment: yes. I will give IP as a server name

Comment: First of all you allow remote connection to your sql server by using sql server configuration Manager

Comment: @sunk why dont give ur cases as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS SQL Server is a multi-user application and MS SQL Server can process queries of multiple users in parallel.

ACID (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID): Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability guarantee that all transactions are processed reliably.

You need to think about:

- Authentication and permissions for operations for your users.
- Transactional isolation level to your application.

Comment: could u pls explain more about the 2 options or give me some important word to search it easily :)

Comment: There are some side effects when you are working with data in parallel.  For example UserA can create record and delete it little bit later in the same transaction. Can UserB get this record or can't ? It depends on your application. Each new transaction isolation level remove one of this side effects (dirty reads in my example), but it also reduce concurrency.  You can read about it here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: thank u for ur article! I need time to read them. if there is any qu, I'll inform u :) if u know some more article, pls let me know

Comment: while I execute this code `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL  SERIALIZABLE`. it has effect in all of my SPs and dont need I use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION;` for each SP ??

Comment: You set transaction isolation level for connection.  You can choose transaction isolation level within connection. Or you can open new conection.

Comment: @demes Which mode is better `Snapshot` or `SERIALIZABLE`?

Comment: There is not better transaction isolation level.  Each of them best in one situations and worst in others.  You must choose transaction isolation level depends on needs of your application.

Comment: @demes as u said I can set `TRAN` on connection, I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h(v=vs.110).aspx). because I want use `DbContext` so I think its better I set `TRAN` in SP or set it for `database` like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx). what do u think? what should i do?! I confused